# Format most recent time

Tags: php, html, sql

I am creating a forum, I want the latest thread post to be formatted in bold or underlined but I'm not sure how to do this.

This is what I have so far

DB Structure;

> ```
> id | threadname |   threaddesc   | posttime
>  1     thread       description     m-d-y
>  2     thread2      description2    m-d-y
> ```

This code echo's the posttime, but I'm not sure how to make the latest time be formatted.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `forum_sub_cats` WHERE `id`='".$row2['id']."'";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
    echo "  <div class=\"pull-right\"> Latest Thread: ".$row3['posttime']."</div>";
}
```

In layman terms something like this:

```
IF($row3['posttime'] > other posttime's) {
    <div class=\"pull-right\"> Latest Thread: <b> ".$row3['posttime']." </b></div>";
} else {    
    <div class=\"pull-right\"> Latest Thread: ".$row3['posttime']." </div>";
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Order your query by descending posttime and format the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order your query by the post time descending

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `forum_sub_cats` WHERE `id`='".$row2['id']."' ORDER BY posttime DESC
```

Then when formatting (sorry forget exact syntax)

```
$count = 0
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2))
{
    IF($count == 0) 
    {
        echo <div class=\"pull-right\"> Latest Thread: <b> ".$row3['posttime']." </b></div>";
        $count++
    } 
    else 
    {    
        echo <div class=\"pull-right\"> Latest Thread: ".$row3['posttime']." </div>";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all your threads ordered by 'posttime' DESC and then take first, or take last one:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `forum_sub_cats` WHERE `id`='".$row2['id']."' ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_sub_cats WHERE id='".$row2['id']."' ORDER BY posttime DESC LIMIT 1");
    $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
    echo "<div class=\"pull-right\"> Latest Thread: <b>".$row3['posttime']."<b></div>";

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_sub_cats WHERE id='".$row2['id']."' ORDER BY posttime DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 1");
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
          echo "<div class=\"pull-right\"> Latest Thread: ".$row3['posttime']."</div>";
    }
```

Well I wrote this from top of my head but I think it should work, if it doesn't let me know and I'll see what can I do. :D